# Google Cloud Function to delete sub-collections on "missing documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have a Firestore collection called Posts, and each document in Posts could have a sub-collection called Post-Likes and/or Post-Comments. When I delete the Posts document, it does not delete the sub-collection so I am left with a reference to a missing document in Firestore which looks like this:

[image]

I am using the following code in my Google Cloud Function to find references in the Post collection with missing data, then for each document with a missing reference, I want to delete the sub-collections Post-Likes and Post-Comments. For now, I am just try to list the sub-collection document so I can delete them, but I am getting an error.

```
function deleteOrphanPostSubCollections() {

    let collectionRef = db.collection('Posts');

    return collectionRef.listDocuments().then(documentRefs => {
       return db.getAll(...documentRefs);
    }).then(documentSnapshots => {
       for (let documentSnapshot of documentSnapshots) {
          if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
            console.log(`Found document with data: ${documentSnapshot.id}`);
          } else {
            console.log(`Found missing document: ${documentSnapshot.id}`);
            return documentSnapshot.getCollections().then(collections => {
              return collections.forEach(collection => {
                console.log('Found subcollection with id:', collection.id);
              });
            });
          }
       }
       return
    });
}
```

However, I am getting the following error. Please help me resolve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is because there is not `getCollections()` method for a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html).

If you want to list all the collections of the Document corresponding to the `DocumentSnapshot`, you need to use the [`listCollections()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#listCollections) method, as follows:

```
documentSnapshot.ref.listCollections()
  .then(collections => {
    for (let collection of collections) {
      console.log(`Found subcollection with id: ${collection.id}`);
    }
  });
```

---

In addition, note that if you call an asynchronous method in a loop, it is recommended to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in order to return a single Promise that resolves when all the "input" Promises are resolved.

Comment: Hey @ramluro, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?